# Why curl function is returning Resource id #4?

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to post a form in json format using curl to Launch 27 to create a booking. My json data is:

```
  {"booking":{
  "id":55,
  "user_id":5,
  "service_date":"2015-08-15T13:00",
  "services":[{
    "id":1,
    "extras":[{
      "extra_id":1,
      "quantity":1
    }],
    "pricing_parameters":[{
      "pricing_parameter_id":1,
      "quantity":1
    }],
    "service_maids":1,
    "service_hours":1
  },{
    "id":2,
    "extras":[],
    "pricing_parameters":[],
    "service_maids":1,
    "service_hours":2
  }],
  "frequency_id":1,
  "address":"595 Market St",
  "city":"San Francisco",
  "state":"CA",
  "zip":"94105",
  "phone":"462-485-0790",
  "price":"202.0",
  "final_price":"202.0",
  "completed":false,
  "payment_method":"stripe",
  "active":true,
  "discount_code":null,
  "customer_comments":null,
  "sms_notifications":false,
  "flexibility":0,
  "custom_fields":{
    "custom_text":"text",
    "custom_dropdown":{"values":"1"},
    "custom_radio":{"values":"2"}
  }
}}
```

and curl function for this is:

```
  function curl_post($url,$postData){
    $postData = json_encode($postData);
    if(!isset($timeout))
        $timeout=30;
    $curl = curl_init();
     if(isset($referer)){
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    }
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array('X-API-Key: my_test_api_key',
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Accept: application/launch27.v2"));
    $html = curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
    return $html;
}
```

Here the given json is sent into `$postData` and `$url=https://acme-sandbox.l27.co/api/bookings`
It returns me resourse id #4... I am totally confused about what is going on. I am following Launch 27's documentation https://bitbucket.org/awoo23/api-2.0/wiki/Create_booking.

I have searched about it but couldn't find sufficient criteria to resolve this. Can you please help me.

Comment: Not reproducible with the given code, can we see how you call this function and print its response?

Comment: please can you set `curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,TRUE)` and see what's going on.